# How to use same image for every row and column in a grid view android?

Tags: android

How to use same image for every row and column in a grid view. In my application from service i got maxcol and maxrow. Based on the condition i want to create a grid view with same image. If maxcol 5 and maxrow 14, Now i want to create grid view 14x5 with same image. Please help me.

main Activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    GridView grid;
    RelativeLayout r1;
    int maxrows, maxcol;
    ArrayList<LayoutData> data = new ArrayList<LayoutData>();
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

              @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        new GetRoute().execute("http://sb2.reloadit.in/TravelServices.asmx/Getlayout");

       }

     private     class GetRoute extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
            /*String mJourneyDate;
            public GetData(String pJourneyDate) {
                this.mJourneyDate = pJourneyDate;
            }*/ProgressDialog pd = null;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String response;

                    try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("RouteScheduleID","430723410"));

                         nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JourneyDate","2014-12-18"));


                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                        HttpResponse responce = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                        HttpEntity httpEntity = responce.getEntity();

                        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                        Log.d("response is", response);

                        return new JSONObject(response);

                    } catch (Exception ex) {

                        ex.printStackTrace();

                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) 
                {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    //Log.v("TAG_RESULTadapter",""+result);

                    pd.dismiss();
                    if(result != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {


                            JSONObject jobj = result.getJSONObject("Response");
                            String message = jobj.getString("Message");
                            String issuceess = jobj.getString("IsSuccess");

                            if(issuceess.equals("true"))
                            {

                                JSONObject layout = result.getJSONObject("Layout");  
                                // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+layoutarray);
                                  maxrows=layout.getInt("MaxRows");

                                  maxcol=layout.getInt("MaxColumns");
                                  grid.setNumColumns(maxcol);


                                    JSONArray routearray = layout.getJSONArray("SeatDetails");
                                    for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

                                     String Row = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Row");
                                 // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+Row);
                                     String Col = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Col");
                                     String Height = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Height");
                                  String  Width = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Width");
                                     String SeatNo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SeatNo");
                                  String Gender = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Gender");

                                         String Deck = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Deck");
                                         String IsAvailable = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsAvailable");
                                      String  Fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
                                       LayoutData ld= new LayoutData();
                                        ld.setRow(Row);
                                        ld.setCol(Col);
                                        ld.setHeight(Height);
                                        ld.setWidth(Width);
                                        ld.setSeatno(SeatNo);
                                        ld.setGender(Gender);
                                        ld.setDeck(Deck);
                                        ld.setIsavailable(IsAvailable);
                                        ld.setFare(Fare);
                                        data.add(ld);



                                     Log.v("TAG_Maxfare",""+Fare);
                                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                     map.put("Row", Row);
                                     map.put("Col", Col);
                                     map.put("Height", Height);
                                     map.put("Width", Width);
                                     map.put("SeatNo", SeatNo);
                                     map.put("Deck", Deck);
                                     map.put("IsAvailable", IsAvailable);
                                     if(SeatNo.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                                         map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.noseat);
                                        }
                                     else{
                                          if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                              map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seatgreen);
                                          }
                                         /* if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                                              map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seatgreen);
                                          }*/else if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                                              map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.seat);
                                          }
                                        }
                                     map.put("Fare", Fare);
                                     sheetdetails.add(map);

                                    }
                                    CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, sheetdetails);
                                    grid.setAdapter(adapter);

                            }
                        }


                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Network Problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
}
}
```

**ADAPTER CLASS:**

```
![import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomGrid extends BaseAdapter{
     private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     public CustomGrid(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails) {
         mContext = c;
         this.sheetdetails= sheetdetails;
    }@Override
     public int getCount() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return sheetdetails.size();
     }@Override
     public Object getItem(int position) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return sheetdetails.get(position);
     }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            HashMap<String, String> map = sheetdetails.get(position);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(map.get("seat_img")));


        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
  }][1]
```

json:

```
 {
    "ExtensionData": {},
    "Response": {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "Message": "",
        "IsSuccess": true
    },
    "Route": {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "RouteScheduleId": 428205707,
        "JourneyDate": "/Date(1418668200000)/",
        "CompanyId": 3964,
        "CompanyName": "KPN Travels",
        "FromCityId": 2667,
        "FromCityName": "hyderabad",
        "ToCityId": 2445,
        "ToCityName": "bangalore",
        "DepartureTime": "/Date(1418716800000)/",
        "DepTime": "2014-12-16T13:30:00",
        "ArrivalTime": "/Date(1418752800000)/",
        "ArrTime": "2014-12-16T23:30:00",
        "Fare": 1000,
        "SeaterFareNAC": 0,
        "SeaterFareAC": 1000,
        "SleeperFareNAC": 0,
        "SleeperFareAC": 0,
        "HasAC": true,
        "HasNAC": false,
        "HasSeater": true,
        "HasSleeper": false,
        "BusLabel": "MULTI AXLE",
        "RouteRemarks": null,
        "BusTypeName": "2+2 (MULTI AXLE) : 44",
        "CommPCT": 0,
        "CommAmount": 90
    },
    "Layout": {
        "ExtensionData": {},
        "MaxRows": 14,
        "MaxColumns": 5,
        "SeatDetails": [
            {
                "ExtensionData": {},
                "Row": 0,
                "Col": 2,
                "Height": 1,
                "Width": 1,
                "SeatNo": "",
                "Gender": "M",
                "IsAisle": true,
                "Deck": 1,
                "IsAC": true,
                "IsSleeper": false,
                "IsAvailable": false,
                "Fare": 0,
                "ChildFare": 0,
                "InfantFare": 0
            },
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67129/discussion-on-question-by-kartheeki-jampana-how-to-use-same-image-for-every-row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your JSON values in array list.Pass the ArrayList to `CustomGrid.class`

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < routearray.length(); i++) {

        String Row = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Row");
        // Log.v("TAG_routearray",""+Row);
        String Col = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Col");
        String Height = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Height");
        String Width = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Width");
        String SeatNo = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("SeatNo");
        String Gender = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Gender");

        String Deck = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Deck");
        String IsAvailable = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("IsAvailable");
        String Fare = routearray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Fare");
        Log.v("TAG_Maxfare", "" + Fare);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Row", Row);
        map.put("Col", Col);
        map.put("Height", Height);
        map.put("Width", Width);
        map.put("SeatNo", SeatNo);
        map.put("Deck", Deck);
        map.put("IsAvailable", IsAvailable);
        if(SeatNo.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
         map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.blank_img);
        }else{
          if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("Available")){
              map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.avaliable_seat_img);
          }else if(IsAvailable.equalsIgnoreCase("Not Available")){
              map.put("seat_img", ""+R.drawable.not_avaliable_seat_img);
          }
        }
        map.put("Fare", Fare);
        sheetdetails.add(map);
 }

CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, sheetdetails);
yourgridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**CustomGrid.Class**

**change this**

```
 public CustomGrid(Context c, int[] Imageid) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;

 }@Override
 public int getCount() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return Imageid.length;
 }@Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return null;
 }
```

**To**

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 public CustomGrid(Context c,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sheetdetails) {
     mContext = c;
     this.sheetdetails= sheetdetails;
}@Override
 public int getCount() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return sheetdetails.size();
 }@Override
 public Object getItem(int position) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return list.get(position);
 }
```

**In getview**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

            HashMap<String, String> map = sheetdetails.get(position);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.valueOf(map.get("seat_img")));

        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
```

Comment: yugesh,i tried but view is not correctly aligned.but it is working. i think i need to take row and col condition from json. am i right yugesh?

Comment: @KartheekiJampana share the screen shot.

Comment: yugesh, i am not able share a screen. it asks 10 reputatuions

Comment: @KartheekiJampana below your Question bluefeet add you in chat.Click the moved to chat.i think you can share screen shot there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want same image, then instead of using this:

```
imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
```

in your `getView` method, just set a single image resource:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher); //replace id with your drawable id
```

You don't need to maintain array of drawables if you have a single image to set in all items of a GridView.

**EDIT**

If you want to pass Array of image resource to BaseAdapter, then you can pass array with one image resource. Like this:

```
int[] Imageid = new int[]{R.drawable.myimage};
```

And just use Imageid[0] for all items instead of Imageid[position].

```
imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[0]);
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

If you want to change value based on availability of seat, you can use a array of 2 images:

```
int[] Imageid = new int[]{R.drawable.available_seat, R.drawable.not_available_seat};
```

In your `getView` method, just check availability from variable **IsAvailable** that you get in json response and set image resource accordingly:

```
if(isAvailable)  //you will need to declare a boolean variable and set it to true or false based on IsAvailable's value
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[0]);
else
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[1]);
```

Hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: then how do i add this in class file.                      CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(MainActivity.this, imageId);

Comment: Didn't you ask for showing only one image at the first place?

Comment: sorry,  i am asking for based on maxrow and maxcol condition every grid will contain same image. if maxrow is 10 and maxcol five, then i need to set a 10x5 with same image

Comment: sorry MagicalIphoneix. My need is.... i have a service. the service  gives me maxrow and maxcol. based on this, i need to design a grid view. Every grid contain same image. It is seat allocation. if availability is there every image looks same. But if no availability the image in grid  changes its color(another image)

Comment: So there are basically two images, right? and you get some variable say `String available = "YES"` or `String available = "NO"` for each item, right?

Comment: yes from json i also get  "IsAvailable": false. and "IsAvailable": true.  based on this the image will be change. I am really new in android. so i  don't know whether gridview  using is correct or wrong?

Comment: sorry to say like this MagicalIphoenix. Please edit your code in my adapter class. my json parsing in class file, then how do i get Isavailable in adapter class.